# JTabbedPane: how to perform action only on active tab

Tags: swing, user-interface, netbeans, jtabbedpane

I would like to save only the text on the currently selected tab(Tab1 one) which I added in the design aspect of netbeans and is separate from my new tab function.

My save function works for all other tabs besides tab 1.

Here is my attempt and getting the save to gather text from tab 1 if tab 1 is selected:

```
public void Save_As()
  {

    fileChooserTest.setApproveButtonText("Save");
    int actionDialog = fileChooserTest.showOpenDialog(this);

    File fileName = new File(fileChooserTest.getSelectedFile() + ".txt" );
    try{
    if(fileName == null)
        return;

     BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileChooserTest.getSelectedFile() + ".txt"));

         String text = ((JTextArea)TabPane.getSelectedComponent()).getText();
         if((TabPane.getTitleAt(TabPane.getSelectedIndex())).equals("Doc1.txt"))
         {
             bw1.write(this.TextArea.getText());   
         }
         else
         {
             bw1.write(text);
             bw1.close();   
         }

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Is an exception thrown? MVC Pattern?

Comment: yes no errors, just not reading text from TextArea when i create a save file

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close the BufferedWriter. just add one line to close it will solve your issue.

To make it much better, you should use try ... catch ... finally, and put the BufferedWriter.close() in the finally section.

```
     if((TabPane.getTitleAt(TabPane.getSelectedIndex())).equals("Doc1.txt"))
     {
         bw1.write(this.TextArea.getText());   
         bw1.close();// you need to close it here.
     }
     else
     {
         bw1.write(text);
         bw1.close();   
     }
```